# how to validate duplicate values in a dropdown ussing reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How do i validate a dropdown which have certain values which is popping from database on page load from taking duplicate values using reactjs validations, i am totally new to reactjs and trying to learn validations in reactjs, please help.

I want the message to pop up when a user selects an existing value and tries to insert the same value by hitting the submit button.

Comment: So you allow multi-select in your dropdown? The user can select multiple identical values in your dropdown?